# How to Add multiple security schemes Bearer and ApiKey in swashbuckle

Tags: swashbuckle, bearer-token

can anyone suggest how to add multiple security schemes in Swashbuckle? and declaring both schemes are applicable globally 
1. Bearer Token and
2. Apikey

Answer (score 0):

adding the scheme as bearer and custom apikey scheme solved what i needed

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Name = "Token",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    Description = "Please enter your token",
    Scheme = "bearer"
});

c.AddSecurityDefinition("X-ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Name = "X-ApiKey",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Description = "Please enter your Api Key",
    Scheme = "x-apikey"
});
```

if there is a better approach please post the answer.

and please provide the comments as well when downvote so i would know what the reason.